# Apple iMessage - ForceICQPlainText

Tags: plist, icq, imessage

I want to change ForceICQPlainText in ~/Library/Preferences/com.Apple.iChat.AIM.plist so my iMessage doesn't sends HTML-Code. But after I changed it and restarted my Mac 7 times I gave up.

**Nothing seems to work:**

ForceICQPlainText = ":true";

ForceICQPlainText = true;

ForceICQPlainText = "true";

ForceICQPlainText = ":yes";

ForceICQPlainText = "YES";

ForceICQPlainText = YES;

ForceICQPlainText = ":true";

What do I need to type, to get only text massages?
I always did a reboot and I locked the file too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

shutdown messages

open ~/Libriary/Preserences in finder

find com.Apple.iChat.AIM.plis file

open the plist in xcode (your might need to install it first, it's free)

[cmd]-F to find the tag

select "YES" in drop-down

[cmd]-S to save

close xcode

[ctrl]-click on the file and select "Get Info"

scroll down to very bottom

select read-only instead read&write

reboot your mac

enjoy